# the float variable doesn't store a floating value

Tags: c++, c++11

```
struct score
{
  int math;
  int science;
  int english;
  int history;
  int mapeh;
  int tle;
  int filipino;
};

struct info
{
  string firstName;
  string lastName;
  score grades;
  float average;
  int studentnum;
  int rank;
  bool remark;
};
```

here is my code

the value stored in the subjects is:

```
 85 87 89 90 94 92 95
```

respectively,

```
vector<info> stud;

for( int i=0; i<stud.size(); i++)
{
 stud[i].average=  (stud[i].grades.math
                   +stud[i].grades.science
                   +stud[i].grades.english
                   +stud[i].grades.history
                   +stud[i].grades.mapeh
                   +stud[i].grades.tle
                   +stud[i].grades.filipino)/7;
}
```

the value stored in stud[i].average should be 90.28 but instead it is only 90.

what have i missed? i have tried using the debugger and it shows me 90 (no decimals)

using setprecision it will only show me 90.00 not 90.28

i have also tried changing the data type for the subjects to float, and it didnt work.

thank you.

Comment: An integer divided by an integer gives you an integer.  All you're doing is adding up integers and then dividing by 7, which is an integer -- result -- integer.

Comment: All of your grades objects are integers. You then divide the sum of these integers by another integer which gives you an integer. Try changing the `7` to a `7.0`.

Comment: so divide by 7.0, I think

Comment: you need to divide it by 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to this:

```
stud[i].average=  (stud[i].grades.math
                   +stud[i].grades.science
                   +stud[i].grades.english
                   +stud[i].grades.history
                   +stud[i].grades.mapeh
                   +stud[i].grades.tle
                   +stud[i].grades.filipino)/7.0;
```

`(int)/(float)` will give you a `(float)` result.